# Stitches removal in south Korea

Tags: health, insurance, south-korea

I suddenly had to get just some small stitches on my wrist and it has to come off in 10 days and I will be in Korea at that time so I was wondering where I can go get it removed and how much will it cost?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable Travel question. Put another way: how might a traveler obtain medical care for a non-urgent matter while in a foreign land, and what might it cost? That's a challenge that might appear for any of us.

Comment: Where in South Korea?  I have an app on my iPad that uses data from Open Street Map.  If I type "clinic" in the search form, I will get a list of them nearby, and spots on the map.  Or "hospital."  Cost, I can't tell you.

Comment: You might want to ask your doctor/hospital whether they can come out before/after your trip to Korea.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.